# Solr - Upload XML file, process with XSLT and supply extra field values in URL

Tags: xml, http, xslt, solr, search-engine

I'm trying to upload an XML document (RSS feed) to Solr. I call this to index the file

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/1-3/update?commit=true&commitWithin=10000&tr=updateXml.xsl&literalsOverride=true&literal.client_uid=3" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary @myfile.xml
```

The core name is `1-3`, it processes the file correctly and I can search all the products and fields I have specified in the schema.xml when I don't include the `client_uid` in the schema or make it an `optional` field.

This is an extra field that I'd like to include in the URL (documents on their own don't have this value)

```
<field name="client_uid" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" required="true"/>
```

My file has around 22,000 documents in it. I try to supply the value via the `literal.client_uid` parameter in the URL but I'm getting this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">3007</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">[doc=117755] missing required field: client_uid</str><int name="code">400</int></lst>
</response>
```

I'm using `Solr 5.4.0`

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. As **@Karsten R.** explained it won't work because the request handlers are different and the UpdateRequestHandler doesn't support it.

I have decided to use an `updateRequestProcessorChain` (in solrconfig.xml) and created a `.jar` library with a new `UpdateRequestProcessorFactory` class which I included in the processor chain.

Snapshot from `solrconfig.xml`

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="mychain">
  <processor class="mypackage.solr.MyNewProcessorFactory"/>
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>`
```

Code for the Solr plugin (this `.jar` file goes into `lib` folder where `solr.xml` is - you need to create the `lib` folder yourself first time)

```
package dreamagility.solr;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.SolrParams;
import org.apache.solr.request.SolrQueryRequest;
import org.apache.solr.response.SolrQueryResponse;
import org.apache.solr.update.AddUpdateCommand;
import org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessor;
import org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessorFactory;

/**
 * Created by Daniel on 06/01/2016.
 *
 * Adds extra tags to each document to be able to filter based on the client id it belongs to
 * This is something that is not included as a part of the feed which is indexed but it will be supplied with
 * the URL as a parameter.
 */
public class MyNewProcessorFactory extends UpdateRequestProcessorFactory {

    @Override
    public UpdateRequestProcessor getInstance(SolrQueryRequest solrQueryRequest, SolrQueryResponse solrQueryResponse, UpdateRequestProcessor updateRequestProcessor) {
        return new MyNewProcessorFactory(solrQueryRequest, solrQueryResponse, updateRequestProcessor);
    }
}

class MyNewProcessorFactoryextends UpdateRequestProcessor {
    private SolrQueryRequest solrQueryRequest;
    private SolrQueryResponse solrQueryResponse;
    private UpdateRequestProcessor updateRequestProcessor;

    public MyNewProcessorFactory(SolrQueryRequest _solrQueryRequest, SolrQueryResponse _solrQueryResponse, UpdateRequestProcessor _updateRequestProcessor) {
        super(_updateRequestProcessor);

        this.solrQueryRequest = _solrQueryRequest;
        this.solrQueryResponse = _solrQueryResponse;
        this.updateRequestProcessor = _updateRequestProcessor;
    }

    @Override
    public void processAdd(AddUpdateCommand cmd) throws IOException {
        SolrInputDocument document = cmd.getSolrInputDocument();
        SolrParams params = this.solrQueryRequest.getParams();

        int clientId = params.getInt("clientId");

        document.addField("client_uid", clientId);

        super.processAdd(cmd);
    }
}
```

And my HTTP call looks like this

`curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/1-3/update?commit=true&commitWithin=10000&tr=updateXml.xsl&overwrite=true&clientId=3update.chain=mychain" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary @myfile.xml`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about the use of `literalsOverride`-Parameter in an update-request.

The answer in short: In default solrconfig.xml the path `/update` is connected to [UpdateRequestHandler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Index+Handlers#UploadingDatawithIndexHandlers-UsingXSLTtoTransformXMLIndexUpdates) (which support parameter `tr`) and the path `/update/extract` is connected to (tika)[ExtractingRequestHandler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Data+with+Solr+Cell+using+Apache+Tika#UploadingDatawithSolrCellusingApacheTika-InputParameters) (with parameter `literalsOverride`).

In your case `/update` with `tr` is a good idea, but you can not use `literalsOverride` is this case. You also can not access the url-parameters from inside your XSL-Transformation (which would be possible for `XSLTResponseWriter`).

imho you have four possiblities:

- generate updateXml1.xsl and updateXml2.xsl and updateXml3.xsl witih the only difference in setting the value of your field
- use different schema.xml for your different cores and set your value as default-values in schema.xml
- change your RSS feed before you sending it to solr
- change solr org.apache.solr.handler.loader.XMLLoader.getTransformer(String, SolrQueryRequest)

Comment: Thanks I've figured it out after digging through their docs and experimenting a lot - done it by using an UpdateRequestProcessorChain and creating a new UpdateRequestProcessorFactory which reads the URL parameters for inputs. Still new to Solr but getting the hang of it. Just posting the answer now.

Comment: I agree: the UpdateRequestProcessorChain is the best place and at time there is no suitable UpdateRequestProcessorFactory (e.g. DefaultValueUpdateProcessor only supports parameter in configuration file)